# Same source and destination register in ldr

Tags: assembly, arm

Is it legal to do `ldr r0,[r0]` in ARM assembly?

Comment: Why don't you want just to try and find out?

Comment: early arm cores might have had an issue, but from the arm7 (armv4) forward I have used that instruction on many different cores and had no problems, arm or thumb mode...How you find out about these things is look at the technical reference manual for the specific core, it will specify such limitations.  also the arm arm, arm archiectural reference manual, for the family (armv7 armv6, etc) might also tell you.

Comment: @Ademiban I did try it out and it did work. But I wanted to be sure since not everything that apparently works is nessecarily defined. For example, reading writing past the end of a buffer can work but that doesn't mean it's defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When in doubt, always refer to the ARM Architecture Reference Manual, which can be found on arm.com.  It says:

```
The destination register. The SP can be used. The PC can be used, provided the
instruction is either outside an IT block or the last instruction of an IT block.
If the PC is used, the instruction branches to the address (data) loaded to the PC.
In ARMv5T and above, this branch is an interworking branch, see Pseudocode details of
operations on ARM core registers on page A2-12.
```

It does not say that the destination register cannot be the same as the base register.  I.e., the answer is YES, they can be the same.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, and it will fetch the value where r0 points to, and load the register r0 with it.
When in doubt, you can use an emulator to test it out. I use the [VBA](http://vba.ngemu.com/) GBA emulator which, albeit GBA-specific, is a good ARM emulator.To learn the basics on GBA programming so that you can do that kind of testing, visit [this](http://www.coranac.com/tonc/text/asm.htm) tutorial.

Comment: the emulators cannot know what the hardware does for such things, so dont trust them.  vba doesnt match the hardware anyway, there are enough differences.

Comment: the instruction set will let you encode this instruction, if that is the question then yes it will...

Comment: @dwelch Yes, but not enough to prevent them from being used to try small things like the one in question.And I am talking about ARM assembly testing, not GBA testing.I do not think there is an instruction not correctly implemented in VBA :)

Comment: Understood, vba is not quite gba compatible, I dont know if the incompatibility is in the arm core or outside.  so that is a fair enough statement that it may not be the core.  Another fair statement is if ARM declares something UNPREDICTABLE, you need to understand that even if your code happens to work on real hardware or an emulator.  You cannot ask the hardware or the emulator if it works, one experiment does not determine design success.  ARM's are better documented that pretty much anyone else, use those documents.

Comment: dwelch is completely correct.  An emulator proves nothing except for the behavior of the emulator.  UNPREDICTABLE instructions may work most of the time, and when they fail they will be very hard to figure out or reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The encoding is valid both for arm and thumb instruction sets from ARMv4 on certainly.

Look at the ARM ARM (ARM Architectural Reference Manual) (http://infocenter.arm.com) for the family you are interested in. In this case ARM7 is ARMv4 which is lumped in with the ARMv5 ARM (used to be the original and only ARM ARM, they were split into separate ARM ARM's).

You are looking for things like this:

```
if ConditionPassed(cond) then
Rd = (Rm * Rs)[31:0]
if S == 1 then
N Flag = Rd[31]
Z Flag = if Rd == 0 then 1 else 0
C Flag = unaffected in v5 and above, UNPREDICTABLE in v4 and earlier
V Flag = unaffected
```

for mul or this

```
Specifying R15 for register <Rd>, <Rm>, or <Rs> has UNPREDICTABLE results.
```

or this

```
Operand restriction: Specifying the same register for <Rd> and <Rm> was previously described as producing UNPREDICTABLE results. There is no restriction in ARMv6, and it is believed all relevant ARMv4 and ARMv5 implementations do not require this restriction either, because high performance multipliers read all their operands prior to writing back any results.
```

For LDR instruction in the ARMv4/5 manual:

Operand restrictions
If  specifies base register write-back, and the same register is specified for  and , the results are UNPREDICTABLE.

I think what that means is this instruction

```
ldr r0,[r0,#+/-offset_12]!
```

Is unpredictable as you are telling the instruction to save the load value and the calculated address to r0, only one can win, and sounds like it is a toss up.  Without the ! at the end the only thing written to r0 is the value loaded.  And there are no comments on restrictions (in rev I of the original ARM ARM, going back to say rev B and C of the ARM ARM and E which were printed editions, all varied between each other in this respect, which is why I think arm uses the term "relevant").  For the mul I cut and pasted above.

The thumb instructions make no comment on restrictions or unpredictable behavior.

Now if you meant ARMv7 when you tagged this with ARM7 look at one of the ARMv7 manuals

for ARMv7 from the ARMv7-AR manual same issue:

```
LDR<c> <Rt>, [<Rn>, #+/-<imm12>]!
if wback && n == t then UNPREDICTABLE;
```

Other than that and the use of r15 there are no restrictions on using the instruction in that manner.

Comment: ldr r0,[r0],#4 should also have the same problem as ldr r0,[r0,#offset]!, but ldr r0,[r0] is okay.